# How to create optimized select with the Java API (with gremlin)?

Tags: java, orientdb

I have a query in SQL that does a direct search, but when I try to implement it in the Java API (with Gremlin) it does a slow sequential search.

The query is:
`SELECT FROM ? where outE().inV() contains ?`

Any ideas on how to write it optimized in the Java API (with Gremlin)?

I am actually using Scala but Java should be similar, example:

```
graph
    .getNoTx
    .V()
    .hasLabel("Class")
    .outE("Edge")
    .inV()
    .has("Class", "Field", "Value")
    .toList
```

Comment: As always, make sure everything mentioned in the WHERE clause is indexed. The EXPLAIN command should really tell you all you need to know.

Comment: When I run the select the explain says its indexed but when I convert it to Java is goes sequential. I am not sure what I am missing in the Java side. I should not need more indexes since the select directly works.

Comment: How are you executing it in Java? Could you please post some code?

Comment: Just added an example.